# UITableViewCell selection backgroundColor change not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` class that looks like this:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        print("Selected: ", selected)

        if selected {
            self.backgroundColor = .red
        } else {
            self.backgroundColor = .white
        }
    }

    override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)

        print("Highlighted: ", highlighted)

        if highlighted {
            self.backgroundColor = .red
        } else {
            self.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

And then in my `UITableViewDelegate` I added this code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    // Navigate to the next screen
}
```

However, both `print()` statements are always false. And the `backgroundColor` never changes. Anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you set tableview property tableView.allowsSelection = true?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all other code just replace your `UITableViewCell` class with this

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.backgroundColor = selected ? .red : .white
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this helps? It seems like you’re simply suggesting using a ternary instead of `if` will help OP’s problem.

Comment: @Nate You just need to remove all the code from **CustomTableViewCell** and **tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)** and replace CustomTableViewCell code with my code and check it while you click it automatically highlight with a red background.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the two issue in your code. Please refer below issue along with the solution.

Please use the below code to set background color of `UITableViewCell`

```
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
```

Instead of

```
    self.backgroundColor = .red
```

Just replace `didSelectRowAt` method if want to change color permanently otherwise keep as it is.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

Refer below attached source code of the demo application. If any further help required.

[Source Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QoaaEHQhAXwG990TCJ_4hAo4tZlhaJeO/view?usp=sharing)